# find owner's gmail address

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

Before coming to the problem, the use case of my extension is to redirect to my web application with the selected content on gmail. For this, the gmail address of the loaded gmail should match with the email address that is registered for using my web application. For example, if i have signup the web app with gmail address - abc@gmail.com and now if i open the gmail with the same gmail address i.e abc@gmail.com then the user should be allowed to use extension but if i opened the gmail of xyz@gmail.com then i should not able to use the extension because the opened gmail account's email address does not match with the email registered in web app.

I have created a login in the popup.js for authentication and it works but I have no idea on how to get the owner's email address of that opened gmail so i can match if logged in account has the same email address or not. How can i do this so? Can anyone guide me on this, please?

Comment: That's a somewhat convoluted description of what seems to be a basic task: getting something out of a web page into an extension popup. You need a *content script* and *messaging* or chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know about that content script and message passing but I do not know how can i find who is the owner of the gmail where extension is loaded.

Comment: Isn't it something that's present in the web page? Inspect the page in devtools and find where it's stored, then you can extract it in your content script.

Comment: Do you mean to say inspect the element and find the owner's email address by scraping?

Comment: I said exactly what I meant, hopefully. Not sure what you mean by scraping in this context.

Comment: The idea was, if you have a gmail page already open in the browser you can read it in your content script and extract the owner's email. In case my assumption is wrong, you can probably use *chrome.cookies* API to get gmail cookies and deduce the owner from there. Also, you might want to inspect the code of other gmail extensions in the web store.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by assuming that when you say "email ID" you actually mean "email address" which in turn is the user id for those social media networks

> is it possible to use the API's of any of these Social Media
>   applications to map the email ID I have to a user in those
>   applications and then to get the user's public information?

Yes and No. In order to request profile information from of these social media networks (let's called them just "providers") your app will need to request it on behave of the actual user. That is, the user will need to authenticate itself with these providers through your app. For this to happen, the user will need to provide a minimum amount of information (email and password) and your app will need to authenticate as well...usually through OAuth or a native API by specifying an already issued "App ID" (or Client ID) and an App Secret. This is information you should receive by these providers once you have successfully registered your app with them.

> is anyone aware of any 3rd party products / API's which can help
>   provide this kind of identification?

I'm not too sure and this is out of the scope of Stackoverflow...but, do you really need to add another abstraction layer in your project? Another dependency? Consider interacting directly with these providers, you have more benefits

So, basically, your app will have to get the user to supply his/her credentials in order to request this information. In the case of OAuth, your app will never see these credentials because the authentication process happens outside your app, all your app will receive is an access token to request the information that is available within the scope of the access token. By that I mean, you have to request specific permissions. There's a lot of information available on the developer's site of these providers and I'm sure you'll get around it without any problems, but feel free to ask if something is not clear enough.